# Unable de reload customer data section

Tags: magento2, section, customer-data

I discover that some native route are listed in the section xml file without any section :

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
    <action name="customer/account/logout"/>
    <action name="customer/account/loginPost"/>
    <action name="customer/account/createPost"/>
    <action name="customer/account/editPost"/>
    <action name="customer/ajax/login">
        <section name="checkout-data"/>
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
</config>
```

In this case the SectionConfigConverter.php will add '*' to signify all sections need to be reloaded. But when one of this route are used, magento try to reload this sections and I got :

> "*" section source is not supported

It doesn't seem that the native code is able to deal with the '*' it has added itself.
Have you already encounter/resolve this bug ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you tell more about how to reproduce that error?

Comment: You can reproduce this bug by calling jQuery.post('/index.php/customer/account/createPost/', []) in your web browser console (I known this call is useless, but it's the easiest and fastest way to reporduce the bug i found)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't understand why this is not working out of the box, but here is workaround for issue:

Plugin which makes this job. In case the **`*`** symbol was found in list of section names it makes the section name equals `null` which means for the `Magento\Customer\CustomerData\SectionPool` class to update all the sections.

> etc/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <!-- Plugins -->
    <type name="Magento\Customer\CustomerData\SectionPool">
        <plugin name="workaround_update_all_sections"
                type="MageWorx\CustomerDataFix\Plugin\UpdateAllCustomerDataSections"
                sortOrder="10"
                disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/MageWorx/CustomerDataFix/Plugin/UpdateAllCustomerDataSections.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © MageWorx. All rights reserved.
 * See LICENSE.txt for license details.
 */

namespace MageWorx\CustomerDataFix\Plugin;

use Magento\Customer\CustomerData\SectionPool;

/**
 * Class UpdateAllCustomerDataSections
 *
 * Update all sections in case the wildcard symbol was found in the sections-to-update array
 */
class UpdateAllCustomerDataSections
{
    /**
     * @param SectionPool $subject
     * @param array|null $sectionNames
     * @param bool $updateIds
     * @return array
     */
    public function beforeGetSectionsData(
        SectionPool $subject,
        array $sectionNames = null,
        $updateIds = false
    ) {
        // Trying to find a wildcard in the "sections-to-update" array
        if (!empty($sectionNames) && array_search('*', $sectionNames) !== false) {
            // If found drop all section names to allow update of all sections
            $sectionNames = null;
        }

        return [$sectionNames, $updateIds];
    }
}
```

*Complete code (module) could be found [here on GitHub](https://github.com/SiarheyUchukhlebau/MageWorx_CustomerDataFix).*

I found a strange code and I think that it should be responsible for this:

> Magento_Customer/js/section-config.js

```
    getAffectedSections: function (url) {
        var route = canonize(url),
            actions = _.find(sections, function (val, section) {
                var matched;

                if (section.indexOf('*') >= 0) {
                    section = section.replace(/\*/g, '[^/]+') + '$';
                    matched = route.match(section);

                    return matched && matched[0] == route; //eslint-disable-line eqeqeq
                }

                return route.indexOf(section) === 0;
            });

        return _.union(_.toArray(actions), _.toArray(sections['*']));
    },
```

but a route could match the ***** section only in case it has no `/`. I don't know how it could be achieved in real world :\ Maybe it could be useful for you somehow.

Comment: Thank you for your response,
I think your plugin will resolve the bug, but I found this strange that magento can't deal with this case natively. I find a way around by explicitly liste the sections for these routes in my sections.xml file. About the strange code you found in js, I think it is used for global url such as customer/account/*

Comment: @PierreGauthier This plugin does not prevent loading in case * was not found in the list of section names. In case the * exist in the section names array it just reload all the sections: you can see the `\Magento\Customer\CustomerData\SectionPool::getSectionsData()` method where code, which is responsible for update sections, looks like `$sectionsData = $sectionNames ? $this->getSectionDataByNames($sectionNames) : $this->getAllSectionData();`. So when the `$sectionNames === null` all sections will be reloaded.